# string "" is assigned to a variable despite having a value

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio, debugging

So I run my code in Visual Studio:

```
    #include "Class_Menu_Items.h"

    using namespace std;

    void mainMenu()
    {
       string menuItems[] = { "Start" , "Options" , "Help" , "Quit" };
       int index, menuItemChosen;

       Menu MainMenu[3];

       //assign values to all main menu
       for (index = 0; index <= 4; ++index);
       {
            MainMenu[index].setMenuName(menuItems[index]);

            cout << "[" << index + 1 << "] " << MainMenu[index].getMenuName() << endl;
       }

       cout << endl << "Choose a menu item: ";

       cin >> menuItemChosen;
   }

   void Menu::setMenuName(string _menuName)
   {
       menuName = _menuName;
   }

   string Menu::getMenuName()
   {
       return menuName;
   }

   Menu::Menu()
   {

   }
```

However VS debugger states error code 0x0078f55c stating:

```
    MainMenu    0x0078f55c {{menuName="" }, {menuName="" }, {menuName="" }} Menu[3]
    +       [0] {menuName="" }  Menu
    +       [1] {menuName="" }  Menu
    +       [2] {menuName="" }  Menu
    -       MainMenu[index] {menuName="\x18Ú¹" }    Menu
    +       menuName    "\x18Ú¹" std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
```

I don't seem to get what the problem is 'cause I believe that I there are values in menuItems[], not blank. So what was the cause of the problem here which I didn't seem to notice? Thanks for any answers in advance :)

Comment: `MainMenu` is an array of size 3 but you're trying to access 5 indicies? (0 - 4)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems at

```
       MainMenu[index].setMenuName(menuItems[index]);
```

Since MainMenu is array of three and menuItems is array of four, and your loop tries to access five elements in both..

Also, you should remove the semicolons in your for statement

Answer (score 0):

**Problems -**

1) You are trying to access the fifth element (index = 4) in MainMenu error in your for loop.

2) You have a semicolon after the for loop.

**Solution -**

Just change the following line -

```
for (index = 0; index <= 4; ++index);
```

to

```
for(index = 0; index < 4; ++index)
```

Comment: You do not correct the first problem in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 'mainMenu' method:

```
void mainMenu()
{
    string menuItems[] = { "Start", "Options", "Help", "Quit" };
    const int menuItemCount = sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(menuItems[0]);
    int index, menuItemChosen;

    Menu MainMenu[menuItemCount];

    //assign values to all main menu
    for (index = 0; index < menuItemCount; ++index)
    {
        MainMenu[index].setMenuName(menuItems[index]);

        cout << "[" << index + 1 << "] " << MainMenu[index].getMenuName() << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Choose a menu item: ";

    cin >> menuItemChosen;
}
```

Your problems have been described previously.

Comment: ohh thank you! I didn't notice the semi-colon after the for loop and VS2015 didn't give me an error code for that. I guess I was too careless.

Anyways, thanks. I just learned the menuItemCount part. I didn't know it was possible. Thank you :)

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, then look to the Warnings window. There should be a warning about these a semicolon.
Use the votes for your thanks ;)

Comment: @stakilobishut，if any replies are helpful for you, please mark it as the answer, so it would be helpful for other members who meet the same issue.